# Extracting the string from the delimiter "/"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
        char* path = "lost+found/d1/dentry";
        char* str = malloc(100);
        char *temp;
        if(NULL == str) perror("malloc failed");
        temp = str;
        while(*path != '/'){
                *str++ = *path++;
        }
        *str = '\0';
        str = temp;
        printf("\n str : %s \n",str);
        return 0;
}
```

o/p:

```
 str : lost+found
```

Is there any library function that can extract only the string with a delimiter "/" [strrchr and srchr Gives the last and first occurences of '/', but the string I search for is lost+found].

Comment: Have a look at `strtok`.

Comment: See [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r)

Comment: @P0W: `strtok_r` is not C but POSIX, just to remember that.

Comment: `char *str = calloc(100, 1);memcpy(str, path, strchr(path, '/')-path);`

Answer (score 0):

[strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) is the most direct way that C library has to offer to tokenize a string. There are some glitches with it though:

- the string you want to tokenize cannot be const
- the given string is changed during the `strtok` calls

If you only need the first segment in that path (as the question suggests) and not all the '/'-delimited tokens [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) may also come in handy (along with [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) and some pointer arithmetic).